# Is this misleading?

Tags: grammar, modifiers

My sentence goes like this:

> Marie and Jackie gather information of possible hiring managers and their company.

What I want to convey is that Marie and Jackie gather information of hiring managers and company where the hiring managers work. Could this be rephrased in order to express clearer idea?

Comment: Replace "of" with "on." If they work at different companies, then replace "company" with "companies."

Answer (score 1):

> Marie and Jackie gather information about (possible) hiring managers and those managers' companies.

The parentheses could be omitted, but I prefer them.

Sometimes clarifying requires more words, sometimes fewer. I could not reckon a way to say what is desired here without repeating *manager* .

> Marie and Jackie gather information of possible hiring managers and their company.

was not perfectly clear. It was not clear what *their* referred to.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 easy ways which you can try using :

> `not only ..but also..`-

"Marie and Jackie gather information of **not only** *the* possible hiring managers **but also** their *companies'*."

---

Simpler and more polished use of the above :

"**Not only do**  Marie and Jackie gather information of possible hiring managers **but also** their *companies'*."

> `..as well as..` -

"Marie and Jackie gather information of *the* possible hiring managers as well as their *companies'*."

`Notice the " (') apostrophe, at the end of *companies'*`

Let me know if this answers your question or you need more examples.

Comment: Confused about why you need apostrophe at the end of "companies' "?